# How to open a .exe file with some parameters and wait to the user close the Command Prompt to continue the code in Python

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I'm trying to build this program but I couldn't find an answer in any questions here that works in this specific problem.

```
import os
import time
from pywinauto import application
import subprocess


#app = application.Application.start("cmd.exe")
#cmd = app.active_.SetEditText('dir')
#cmd.Edit.TypeKeys("dir")

#dir = r"D:\Users\gpaiva\Desktop\Reconhecimento de fala\minicurso-asr\bin"
#cmdline = "HVite -C cfg\hvite_live.conf -g -e -d hmm1 -i mlf\testliveout.mlf -w net\network dics\dictionary lists\models"
#rc = call("start cmd /K " +cmdline, cwd=dir)

#cmd = subprocess.check_output([r"cd D:\Users\gpaiva\Desktop\Reconhecimento de fala\minicurso-asr\bin"])
#hvite = cmd.subprocess.check_output(["HVite -C cfg\hvite_live.conf -g -e -d hmm1 -i mlf\testliveout.mlf -w net\network dics\dictionary lists\models"])
```

I tried in many other ways to do that but I erase, above are th latest attempts.

If anyone can help me I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The start command needs to be launched with the /Wait command

I haven't tested it but something like this:

```
cmdrun = "cmd /K " + cmdline
rc = call("start " + cmdrun + " /WAIT", cwd=dir)
```

Comment: Didn't work either, appeared this error message 'WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified'
But the file is there and is working fine when I execute manually in cmd.exe.